# Use a trigger to insert a value based on a foreign key

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following tables in a mysql database:

item

```
Column              Type            Null Default    Links to    Comments    MIME
item_id (Primary)   int(11)         No              
FK_item_category    int(11)         Yes  NULL   item_category -> item_category_id       
item_name           varchar(45)     Yes  NULL           
item_description    varchar(45)     Yes  NULL           
item_price          decimal(5,2)    Yes  NULL
```

item_category

```
Column                      Type        Null    Default Links to    Comments    MIME
item_category_id (Primary)  int(11)     No              
item_category_name          varchar(45) Yes     NULL
```

order

```
Column              Type            Null    Default           Links to  Comments    MIME
order_id (Primary)  int(11)         No              
FK_order_user_email varchar(45)     Yes     NULL              user -> user_email        
order_time          datetime        Yes     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP           
order_pickup_time   time(6)         Yes     NULL            
order_instructions  varchar(45)     Yes     NULL            
order_gross_total   decimal(10,2)   Yes     NULL            
order_net_total     decimal(10,2)   Yes     NULL
```

order_detail

```
Column                      Type            Null    Default Links to    Comments    MIME
order_details_id (Primary)  int(11)         No              
FK_order_id                 int(11)         Yes     NULL    order -> order_id       
FK_order_item_id            int(11)         Yes     NULL    item -> item_id     
order_detail_unit_price     decimal(5,2)    Yes     NULL            
order_detail_quantity       int(11)         Yes     NULL
```

I have other tables too, but am trying to create a trigger on these tables specifically.

I am trying to create a trigger that will add the **item_price** to the **order_detail** table based on the foreign key **fk_order_item_id**. The trigger will be run after insert, and after update.

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project, let us know if you have a question!

Comment: what do your triggers look like now? How well do they work?

Comment: @BobDalgleish I haven't been able to get a trigger working. I have been able to use a query (with an inner join) to update the **order_detail_unit_price** column, however I need this to be automated so that a price is added each time a new order detail is created or edited.

Here is my query code if it is of any use:
`UPDATE order_detail INNER JOIN item ON FK_order_item_id = item.item_id SET `order_detail_unit_price` = item.item_price WHERE item.item_price IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not using triggers in this way. I think an application service is the correct location for updating your tables. If it has to be in the database then consider the use of a stored procedure. You should consider how you are going to implement security of these tables. Use of a stored procedure can be helpful, because you can grant rights to the procedure for a user, but not to the tables.

Triggers can be used to conduct calculations before inserting or checking for certain criteria.

I believe a service in your application is the best solution for your issue. It should handle the updates and security. In your case it might require multiple services. One for creating an order, possibly one for updating after an order is placed. Maybe another for deleting an order, etc...